# Date object in JSON return data treated as string

Tags: javascript, json, date

I try to get JSON data from an URL and to push the values into a function. 
All JSON values are enclosed by quotes to have a proper JSON format.But in fact not all values are strings.

Here is a JSON sample:

```
table = [
          {
            'date1': 'new Date(2015,13,1)',
            'content': 'this is the content'
          },
          {
            'date1': 'new Date(2015,13,2)',
            'content': 'this is the contentB'
          }
];
```

The file is loaded like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost/json-test";
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var myData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            drawFunction(myData);

        }
 }
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.send();

  function drawFunction(myData) {
      doSomething();            
  }
```

This works - but the "new Date" values are (of course) also returned as strings.
How can I convert them?
The function should use the values like this:

```
table = [
          {
            'date1': new Date(2015,13,1), //as new Date - not as string - without quotes
            'content': 'this is the content'
          },
          {
            'date1': new Date(2015,13,2),
            'content': 'this is the contentB'
          } ];
```

I might doing this completely wrong. Any hint would be appreciated. 
The JSON source file cannot be changed.

Comment: You should consider sending a Unix timestamp instead of trying to send an entire date object.

Comment: I agree with @Juhana, or send month, day, and year values and construct them on the client side.

Comment: JSON is a *string representation* of data.  Its values can only be strings, numbers, booleans, or null.  (see: http://json.org/) You'll need to "convert" the dates to `Date` objects yourself.  You should store the date as a timestamp, then loop over the data to call `new Date` on the values.

Comment: `table = ` is not valid JSON. How are you even able to parse the response?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the enclosing `''` characters around the `new Date` object. They are sending it as a string rather than evaluating the object.

Write this,

```
'date1': (new Date(2015,13,1)).toString()
```

instead of

```
'date1': 'new Date(2015,13,1)'
```

This will return date in the standard format. It can be formatted as well.

**Note**: You cannot send custom objects like `Date` via a JSON, only evaluated strings. (simply because JSON is meant to be a platform independent exchange)